# How to merge tags to a branch while merging a branch A to branch B?

Tags: git, tags, branch, git-branch, semantic-release

I have two branches, `branch-A`(Which has tags `1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2`), `branch-B` (created on top of `branch-A`). We are doing the development in both the branches parallelly.

After `branch-B` was created I did some more releases from `branch-A` (`1.1.3,1.2.0` latest tags). When I am trying to merge `branch-A` into `branch-B` the changes are merged but not tags.

When I am running `git tag --merged branch-B`  I have only `1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2`.

Is there any way I can merge tags also to `branch-B`?, because when I am doing the release from `branch-B` it is again trying to release `1.1.3` tag in `semantic-release` github actions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe the workflow you follow when you say "I merge branch-A to branch-B" ?

Comment: If you use PR + the "squash merge" option, then it will not result in an actual merge in the commit graph, and the tags will not be "imported". Chose another way to merge branch-A into branch-B : either an actual `git merge` + push, or through a PR, but without the "squash" option

Comment: Thanks for the reply., currently I am adding the merge commit (by git merge) by raising the PR and doing squash and merge. As per you, it will not do actual merge in the commit-graph. Do I need to merge the PR without squash and merge right? Is there anywhere in documentation present for how to do a merging?

Comment: A "squash and merge" is not actually a merge at all, so yes, you must not use squash-and-merge if you'd like to have an actual merge.